# Materializecss buttons border styling?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

How do you add border to Materialize css's buttons using built-in classes. For example how do you add white border to this,

```
 <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"   name="action">Submit
<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
.btn.waves-effect.waves-light { border: 2px solid #fff; }
```

Comment: there is no built-in class?

Comment: Hey, glad this did the trick! What exactly do you mean @djangoman ?

Answer (score 2):

In materialize there is no built in [class helper](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html) for adding borders to tags.

You can do this two ways the first would be to add your own separate style sheet and style the `.btn` class yourself separately example

```
.btn {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Or materialize provides the [sass](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) files, so you could change the `.btn` style in `sass\components\_buttons.scss` and then build it yourself with a sass compiler and include that.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe existing answers are just work arounds (though solving the purpose). But correct answer should be overriding corresponding sass variables, which in this case is `$button-radius`.

You can find all variables here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/components/_variables.scss